# Inconsistency in results of aggregating pandas groupby object using numpy.median vs other functions

Tags: python, numpy, aggregate, pandas

Using DataFrame (pandas as  pd, numpy as np):

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [10,11,12,13,15,25,43,70],  
                     'B' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],  
                     'C' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})


In [39]: test
Out[39]: 
    A  B  C
0  10  1  1
1  11  2  1
2  12  3  1
3  13  4  1
4  15  5  2
5  25  6  2
6  43  7  2
7  70  8  2
```

Grouping DF by 'C' and aggregating with np.mean (also sum, min, max) produces column-wise aggregation within groups:

```
In [40]: test_g = test.groupby('C')

In [41]: test_g.aggregate(np.mean)
Out[41]: 
       A    B
C            
1  11.50  2.5
2  38.25  6.5
```

However, it looks like aggregating using np.median produces DataFrame-wise aggregation within groups:

```
In [42]: test_g.aggregate(np.median)
Out[42]: 
      A     B
C            
1   7.0   7.0
2  11.5  11.5
```

(using `groupby.median` method seems to produce expected column-wise results though)

I would appreciate addressing following issues:

1. What is the reason/mechanism of such an outcome?
2. If this behaviour is confirmed, how does it affect recommended "best practices" of aggregating groupings? Could other aggregation functions work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is quite funny. Probably some pandas specialists would want to chime in, but it comes down to a ping-pong between numpy and pandas. Note that the documentation says:

> Function to use for aggregating groups. If a function, must either
>   work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply. If
>   pass a dict, the keys must be DataFrame column names

The first thing is a 2D (array_like) the second method comes down to 1D array_likes being passed to the function you give in.

This means aggregate passes first the 2D series in. In the first case (`np.mean`), numpy knows that arrays have a `.mean` attribute, so it does what it always does it calls this. However it calls it with `axis=None` (default for numpy). This makes Pandas throw an Exception (it wants axis to be 0 or 1 and never None) and it goes to the second step, which passes it as 1D and is foolproof.

However, when you give in `np.median` numpy arrays do not have the `.median` attribute, so it does the normal numpy machinery, which is to flatten the array (ie, typically `axis=None`).

The workaround would be to use `test_g.aggregate([np.median, np.median])` to force it to always take the second path. or what would work too: `test_g.aggregate(np.median, axis=0)` which passes the `axis=0` on into `np.median` and thus tells numpy how to handle it correctly. In generally I wonder if pandas should not at least throw a warning, afterall broadcasting the result to both columns should be almost never what is wanted.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected the problem was about pandas - numpy interface and numpy's array treatment, inspected `aggregate` docstring, but could not draw the conclusion you did ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also as a workaround, please note that pandas has shortcut methods for common operations:

```
In [12]: test.groupby('C').mean()
Out[12]: 
       A    B
C            
1  11.50  2.5
2  38.25  6.5

In [13]: test.groupby('C').median()
Out[13]: 
      A    B
C           
1  11.5  2.5
2  34.0  6.5
```

For things like sum, mean, median, max, min, first, last, std, you can call the method directly and not have to worry about the apply-to-DataFrame-but-failover-to-each-column mechanism in the GroupBy engine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug... so [I added it here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1989).

In the mean time (if you excuse the pun), you could use the [.agg](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html?highlight=agg#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) method:

```
test_g.agg([np.mean,np.median])
        A             B        
     mean  median  mean  median
 C                             
 1  11.50    11.5   2.5     2.5
 2  38.25    34.0   6.5     6.5
```

Comment: `agg` is just a shorthand for `aggregate`, you are however forcing it to work on single columns always, which works around the issue.

Comment: In fact, .agg seems not to work:

`In [6]: test_g.agg(np.median)
Out[6]: 
      A     B
C            
1   7.0   7.0
2  11.5  11.5`

While .agg([x]) works:


`In [7]: test_g.agg([np.median])
Out[7]: 
        A       B
   median  median
C                
1    11.5     2.5
2    34.0     6.5`

The answer from seberg explains that I think.

Comment: Sorry, embarrassing difficulties formating code in comment ;)

Comment: `agg([np.median])` :) yes. I was just trying to work out a link to pass in `axis=0` which is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v 0.12 DataFrame.median is introduced :http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html

Before v 0.12, I don't think the method exists. Instead, you can use numpy.median